# Can not get value outside $(document).ready() {}

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/file_lines",
            type: 'GET',
            // contentType: 'application/json', // format of Data to be sent to the server
            // data: 'json',//Data to be sent to the server
            dataType: 'text', //The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.
            success: function (lines) {
                document.getElementById("tmp").innerHTML = lines
                **console.log(document.getElementById("tmp").innerHTML)**
            },
            error: function (){
                alert("get debug log's lines failed");
                return false;
            }
        });
})

// console.log($('#tmp').html())
**var num = document.getElementById("tmp").innerHTML
console.log(num)**
```

I am so confuse that why I can get innerHtml value of "tmp" in the $(document).ready() but can not get this value outside $(document).ready()! I thought DOM object should be global. So I am quite confuse about this result. Could somebody help me?
[image: here is console output]

Comment: Please share more details. What happens instead?

Comment: [`$(document).ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) is used to make sure the code runs *after* the page has loaded. After the document is ready, if you will. Other code will run *before* that and most likely the element with ID tmp does not exist at that point. I suspect your script is in the `<head>` section and thus gets run before the `<body>` is rendered.

Comment: OK, I missed the fact that you only add content to the tmp element *in the `$(document).ready()`. Which runs after the code that's outside of it. So, there you go.

Comment: HTML is parsed from top to bottom. A script runs in its entirety when it is encountered; any HTML below the `<script>` doesn't exist yet. However the lines in a script do not all run from top to bottom in order; stuff that is inside a function usually won't. Those often only run when an event happens, such as the document finishing loading, or the user clicking something. Your console shows output that looks like an empty string, which is consistent with `<div id="tmp"></div>` so your code works as expected.

Comment: To be clear, what happens in order is 1. the two commands at the bottom of the script run, output is `""`. 2. the document finishes loading and the ready event fires 3. your anonymous function runs, calling $.ajax() 4. the function has no further commands and ends 5. the server sends the reply, the ajax success function runs 6. the server's reply is inserted into the DOM, then output

Comment: Yes, that the reason! thank you very much